# CA SiteMinder offline authentication for thick Client

Tags: java, swing, authentication, offline, siteminder

I am looking for a way to authenticate a standalone thick client when its offline using CA siteminder. I am  already using siteminder for authentication, but now I want to access the application even when its offline.

Is there any way to store the tokens from a previous session and use it again or some other way I can do it?

The application is based on swing java.

Answer (score 0):

SiteMinder relies on a Policy Server to authenticate, authorize, and enforce policies.  This makes offline integration pretty much impossible (as far as I am aware).

Answer (score 0):

We use a siteminder agent called "SiteMinder Agent for SAP WebAS". This agent is installed on a SAP Java As. It's basically deployed as a Login Module [Link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/DE/46/3ce9402f3f8031e10000000a1550b0/content.htm). Im not sure if I can Monitor this login module.